# HA Proxy fails to bind socket on port TCP 2001

Tags: reverse-proxy, redhat, haproxy

'I've been trying to setup HA-Proxy on RH8 with multiple ports and multiple SNI passes. HA Proxy failing to start just because failing to bind 0.0.0.0:2001. No issues with port 443 and 8443. Finally I decided to setup listen with just one port i.e 2001 which fails.
Checked ss -tupln and 2001 is not in use or listening by any other service in the OS.

Firewall is configured to allow TCP- 443, 8443 and 2001.

Below is a glimpse of the configuration I have reached now in test environment.

I have hashed out the actual configuration and now trying with just one frontend.'

```
# Default configuration
defaults
  log global
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

# Frontend configuration for port 2001
frontend https-in
  bind *:2001
  mode tcp
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }
  use_backend servers-https if { req.ssl_sni -i example.com }

# Backend configuration for port 2001
backend servers-https
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server web1 192.168.1.1:2001 ssl verify none
  server web2 192.168.1.2:2001 ssl verify none

# Hashed out configuration below this point
# Frontend configuration for port 8443
#frontend port-8443
#   bind 192.168.148.130:8443
#   bind 192.168.148.130:2001
#   mode tcp
#   use_backend awcm if { req.hdr(host) -i */awcm* }
#   default_backend servers-port-8443

# Backend configuration for port 8443

#backend servers-port-8443
#   mode tcp
#   server servers 192.168.1.3:8443


# Backend configuration for port 2001
#backend awcm
#   mode tcp
#   server app3 192.168.1.5:2001
```

Checked existing binded ports on OS
verified the configuration on multiple instances of OS with HAproxy installed
Firewall set to allow incoming ports

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting found that we need to give SELinux permission to the HAProxy process to get access on TCP socket bindings without disabling the SELinux.

Error:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/haproxy from name_bind access on the tcp_socket port 2001.

*****  Plugin bind_ports (85.9 confidence) suggests   ************************

If you want to allow /usr/sbin/haproxy to bind to network port 2001
Then you need to modify the port type.
Do
# semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp 2001
    where PORT_TYPE is one of the following: commplex_main_port_t, http_cache_port_t, http_port_t.

*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.33 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow nis to enabled
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'nis_enabled' boolean.

Do
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
```

To resolve the issue, we need to give SELinux permission to the HAProxy process to get access on TCP socket bindings without disabling the SELinux.

```
setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1
```